# Можно ли сделать в MySQL CREATE TABLE LIKE с триггерами?

Tags: mysql, база-данных, триггер

Возможно ли  перенести триггеры в другую(точно такую же) таблицу в MySQL?
У меня есть таблица test, со временем я её архивирую и на ее месте создаю такую же

```
CREATE TABLE test_new LIKE test;
RENAME TABLE test to test_old;
RENAME TABLE test_new to test;
```

После такого кода мне нужны триггеры из test_old, они были созданы автоматически.

Comment: Возьмите код триггера и выполните в новой базе. Только в начале CREATE TRIGGER

Comment: Зависит от текста триггера. В общем случае автоматически это сделать затруднительно, если текст триггера не позволяет простой заменой имени таблицы получить требуемое.

Comment: Проблема в то что триггеры создаются автоматически.